# Extract total time from logs with Excel

Tags: excel, time

I have an excel with logs of student and I need to calculate the total time they were in the system.
Example of table:

```
Student Logtime
34319   24-11-2014 11:48:13
34319   24-11-2014 11:50:13
34319   24-11-2014 11:52:13
35445   24-11-2014 13:00:47
35445   24-11-2014 13:02:47
35445   24-11-2014 13:04:47
35445   24-11-2014 13:06:47
38601   24-11-2014 13:09:44
38601   24-11-2014 13:11:44
38601   24-11-2014 13:13:44
```

What I need:

```
Student TotalTime
34319   00:04:00
35445   00:06:00
38601   00:04:00
```

Comment: Can there be two logins for the same student?

Comment: It is actually a HeartBeat, so there are many logs from each student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

http://exceltotal.com/buscar-un-valor-y-regresar-multiples-resultados-en-excel/

1. Search time values for each student (one column for each student)
2. Sort (delete error messages from Excel)
3. Use MAX and MIN for each student range column created.

NOTE: The link has spanish Excel formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Student` is in A1, maybe (not sure about when logging stops) extract a list of unique student IDs (say select ColumnA, Sort & Filter, Advanced, Copy to another location, Copy to: $C$1, check Unique records only) and in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=C2,B:B))-MIN(IF(A:A=C2,B:B))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.